# Autoload only registers one class at a time

Tags: php, autoload

I have this autoloader which loads only one class at a time. I can't figure out what is wrong with it.. I initially made to learn as much about PSR-0 as possible, though according [to code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58948/how-can-this-autoloader-be-improved/) I did everything required, but it just won't load two different files, from different namespaces as seen below.

```
class Autoloader
{
    private $pathToClass; 

    //register the path
    function __construct($pathToClass)
    {
        $this->pathToClass = $pathToClass; 
    }

    //load the file
    public function load($class)
    {

        // expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)
        $explode = explode('\\', $class); 

        //get the last exploaded string and append .php so it becomes tar.php
        $class = $explode[count($explode) - 1].'.php'; 

        // required tar.php in the path it is found ex:
        // require '/foo/bar/tar.php' in lowecase to avoid windows/unix conflict
        if(file_exists(strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class))){
             require strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class);

            return true; 
        }

        return false; 
    }   

    // autoload
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}
```

Here is how it is instantiated:

```
$myLibLoader = new Autoloader(__DIR__.'/foo/bar/');
$myLibLoader->register();


$foo =  new foo();
```

### EDIT

The above was the first autoloader I had created, but below I am showing the improved autoloader, which which I have the same problem.

```
<?php 
 class AutoloaderException extends Exception{}

class AutoLoader
{
    private $classDir; 
    private $namespace; 
    public $dirSeparatorSymbol = '\\'; 

    public function __construct($namespace, $classDir)
    {
        $this->classDir = $classDir; 
        $this->namespace = $namespace;

    }

    private function load($class)
    {

        $include_path = str_replace($this->dirSeparatorSymbol, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $this->classDir);

        $classFilename = strtolower(substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1) . '.php');

        if(file_exists($include_path.$classFilename)){
            require $include_path.$classFilename;

            return true; 
        }


        throw new AutoloaderException('Class '.$classFilename. ' could not be loaded'); 
    }   

    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}



/* INITIALIZING The autloader */

$b = new Autoloader('mercury\venus\earth', __DIR__.'/mercury/venus/earth/');
$b->register();

$a = new Autoloader('bar\tar', __DIR__.'/foo/bar/tar/');
$a->register();


$x = new bar\tar;

$y = new mercury\venus\earth;
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run `$foo =  new foo();`?  Is `foo.php` in `__DIR__.'/foo/bar/'`?

Comment: `// expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)` what happens to foo and bar? It looks like you're just throwing the namespace portion away completely

Comment: Sorry about this guys. I posted the original autoloader, which is very different from [this one](http://pastebin.com/7PV7yWjt) I had managed to recreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the crux of your issue was identified in your original CodeReview question, specifically this comment:

> You still don't construct a path from the class qualifier passed to
>   load(). As the question how to do this is offtopic on CodeReview,
>   consider posting on StackOverflow (with a clear explanation on the
>   parts you don't understand). –  @ComFreek

I think, given two classess with no namespace, your autoloader as-is should perform fine.  Once you introduce namespaces though you're going to have an issue because you're not taking it into account at all.

Namespaces are important in PSR-0 because they contain further path information.  For example, you may want all of your classes to live in `/some/directory`, but if you add namespaces to those files (extending your example using the `\Foo\Bar\Tar` class) then according to PSR-0 that class *must* be declared in the file `/some/directory/Foo/Bar/Tar.php`.

Taking this into consideration, these lines must be changed in your autoloader in order for it to become PSR-0 compliant:

```
if(file_exists(strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class))){
    require strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class);
    return true; 
}
```

Specifically, the filepath of the class file you're trying to require should be something like this:

```
$this->pathToClass . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode('/', $class) . '.php';
```

(That is, assuming you take this line out: `$class = $explode[count($explode) - 1].'.php';` )

I'm not sure if you've had the chance, but [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) on Site Point is a great read and covers pretty much everything you need to know regarding PSR-0 and autoloading.

Comment: Hi, can you check my update. I posted the wrong code. The edit is actually the improved autoloader, but which only loads one class at a time

Comment: Are you trying to get this working on Windows, Linux, or Mac? I'm asking because you're making the classname all lowercase, which would cause issues on any file system that has case-sensitivity for filenames (basically all of them except possibly Windows)

Comment: I am using linux. I made them all lowecase, because as you said they were creating problems for me. I use virtualbox in local development and VPS as my online host. So, that for some reason created problems. So I decided to make all lowecase

Comment: I am accepting this one as answer, but if you can, please [check this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161600/autoloader-only-loads-one-class) which is the same but still no answer